# Taking items from a list and inserting a string to the responding items on another list

Tags: python, list, tuples, minesweeper

So I have this assignment where I'm supposed to make a function which does the following:

def function(list1, list2, n), The function needs to to take a random number (n) of items  from the list 2, and then place a string "x" on the responding items on the list 1. (The items taken from list 2 are tuples as in x and y coordinates (x, y))

I was kind of trying to do this with random.sample(list2, n), but from there on out I'm clueless.

If anyone knows how to do this I would be grateful.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The problem description is vague. Please include your own attempt and a [MCVE].

Comment: Wat exactly are "responding items"?